# fullcalendar not loading grid

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, fullcalendar

Im using FullCalendar with Backbone.JS and Require.js

my view loads the calendar header but thats it. Only if I press forward or back month or today button does the grid appear.
I get error message on firebug saying getDaySegmentContainer is undefined.

I thought it might be because the DOM is not ready so I force a render once I done the setting up of views but this makes no difference.

Below is my code, if you require to see the render function of the calendar view let me know.

MainView:

```
    var View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template : _.template(Template),

        initialize : function() {

            this.$el.html(_.template(Template));
            _.extend(this, Backbone.Events);
            this.collection = new EventCollection();

            //$("#calendar").append(_.template(Template));
            // $(this.el).append(_.template(Template));

            this.calendarView = new CalendarView({
                el : $(this.el).find("#calendarDiv"),
                collection : this.collection
            });
            // $(this.el).find("#calendarDiv").append(this.calendarView.el);
            this.calendarView.render();
            //this.collection.fetch();

        },

        render : function() {

            return this;
        }
    });
    return View;
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you go through this http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/

Comment: Yes I did. I had it working perfectly before but my dev team changed the structure of enviroment and added nodes into it. Since then it no longer works. Keep getting the error about segment container being undefined.